# combining strings using recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion

So I'm having a little trouble with the final part of my assignment on recursion. The method needs to use recursion to return a string that is formed from "weaving" together two strings taken in as parameters. For example:

```
weave("aaaa", "bbbb") // should return the string "abababab"
weave("hello", "world") // should return the string "hweolrllod"
weave("recurse", "NOW") // should return the string "rNeOcWurse"
```

Note that the extra characters from the first string—the characters in "urse"—come after the characters that have been woven together.

The important (and annoying) thing is that I'm not allowed to use any iteration loops (for, while, do while).

Here is my code thus far:

```
public static String weave(String str1, String str2)
{
    String word = str1 + str2;
    if(str1 == null || str1.equals("") || str2 == null || str2.equals(""))
    {
        return word;
    }              
    String word1 = weave(str1.substring(0, str1.length() - 1), str2.substring(0, str2.length() - 1));
    System.out.println(word1);
    return word;
}
```

For (Hello, World), my output is:

```
HW
HeWo
HelWor
HellWorl
HelloWorld
```

Obviously my characters aren't weaving, so I'm not sure what to do! Also, as stated above, the method should do not printing. I just added in the `println` statement as a test to see where my program was at.

Comment: tells what your output *should* look like

Comment: @LiviuT. They do state the expected end result at the beginning in the examples.

Comment: @LiviuT. See the first codeblock's comments.

Comment: Try using a private helper function, with a third parameter.

Comment: I think my brain froze when I read the question :) sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something like the following might work.

```
public String weave(String str1, String str2)
{
  if(str1.isEmpty() || str2.isEmpty()) {
    return str1 + str2;
  }
  return str1.substring(0, 1) + str2.substring(0, 1) + weave(str1.substring(1), str2.substring(1));
}
```

The idea is pretty simple: you only need to pop the first character from both input strings and concatenate both characters and the returned value from calling the function recursively with the stripped input strings until one of the input strings is empty in such case you should merely return the non-empty string.

```
weave("abcdef", "12"): "a" + "1" + weave("bcdef", "2")
  |
  +- weave("bcdef", "2"): "b" + "2" + weave("cdef", "")
       |
       +- weave("cdef", ""): "cdef"
```

Resulting in:

```
weave("abcdef", "12"): "a" + "1" + "b" + "2" + "cdef": "a1b2cdef"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is:

```
String word = str1 + str2;
//...
return word;
```

No matter how the recursive call, at the end it just return the result from the first method call when you pass in "hello", "world".

```
String word = str1 + str2; //hello + world
//... other things and the recursive call doesn't matter
//return word; //return the first word variable which is helloworld
```